# How to plot a pre-binned histogram in Excel 2007, without Analysis Toolpak

Tags: excel, excel-2007, charts, histogram

I have two columns of data.  Column A has values.  Column B has bins associated with each value in Column A (so lets say bins 1 to 10).  example:

```
A      B
--     ----
.43    1
.29    4
.23    1
.11    8
...    ...
```

Is it possible to create a histogram chart **without using the analysis toolpak** and ideally not having to post-process this data in frequency counts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to use a PivotChart.  In that way, I don't need to use the Analysis Toolpak AND I don't need to treat the data.  The data can be used as-is.

Comment: How is a PivotChart *not* post-processing your data?! That's just what it does!